# Design pattern for consistent UI

Tags: java, html, jsp, design-patterns, tiles2

I have a Java based web app, which is going to be redesigned (i.e. mainly UI) from scratch.

Now here are the requirements:

1. The major changes are going to be in the UI layer (where it has to
   work on multiple devices like desktop/mobile/tablet with small
   changes in respective UI views)
2. The UI changes would cause changes in the Action layer and "MAY"
   also cause some slight changes in Service layer
3. I want the entire web app (all JSPs) to forcefully use a specific
   template (Header/Body/Footer)

Now my question is which design pattern would be most appropriate to use.

I am from a UI background (and less into Java). So it would be great if you could explain in very SIMPLE/BASIC terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this case, the basic problem is the **separation of concerns** namely the *UI Concern* which renders the UI from the data and the *Business Logic* which generates the data. For these type of problem [Model-View-Controller OR MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) is best suited,

To explain roughly :

**Model** -     is the data mode and business log which generates data

**View** -      the Visual representation of data or UI as we know it

**Controller** - Is an engine which selects the correct view depending on the Data generated

So far MVC remains the most preferred design (or architectural ) pattern for web application. There are numerous MVC frameworkfor java.

For MVC, check out these links [1](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/patterns/MVC-detailed.html),[2](http://nikkobautista.com/using-the-model-view-controller-architecture-to-supercharge-your-web-development), [this one](http://media.techtarget.com/tss/static/articles/content/StrutsFastTrack/StrutsFastTrack.pdf) is struts specific and quite detailed. Don't get overwhelmed :)

From the available frameworks (which are, I heard around 50 odd) [Struts](http://struts.apache.org/) and [Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html) remains the most popular.

Checkout [Developing Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/) , [Developing struts application](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-struts/).

for your listed problems #1 and #2 MVC is good. For your specific problem of #3, there is [Tiles Framework](http://tiles.apache.org/), which works both with [Struts](http://conferences.embarcadero.com/article/32246) and [Spring MVC](http://mhimu.wordpress.com/2009/12/09/spring-mvc-tutorial-using-tiles-2/).

As I understand, you are new to Java and web development, this should be just a good starting point.